# Find the first pattern before the specific substring in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, substring

In Python 3.6.5, say I have a string, read from file, like this:

```
# comments

newmtl material_0_2_8
Kd 1 1 1
Ka 0 0 0
Ks 0.4 0.4 0.4
Ke 0 0 0
Ns 10
illum 2
map_Kd ../images/texture0.png

newmtl material_1_24
Kd 1 1 1
Ka 0 0 0
Ks 0.4 0.4 0.4
Ke 0 0 0
Ns 10
illum 2

newmtl material_20_1_8
Kd 1 1 1
Ka 0 0 0
Ks 0.4 0.4 0.4
Ke 0 0 0
Ns 10
illum 2
d 1.0
map_Kd ../images/texture0.jpg

... and so on ...
```

I'm looping for each texture and I need to get the corresponding material code.

I want to retrieve the substring `material_*` corresponding to a certain `texture*`, which I know the name.

So for example, if I have `texture0.jpg`, I want to return `material_20_1_8`; if I have `texture0.png` then I want to have `material_0_2_8`.

How can I do it in this way?

```
f=open('path/to/file', "r")
if f.mode == 'r':
    contents =f.read() # contains the string shown above
for texture in textures: # textures is the list of the texture names
    material_code = ?
```

Or any other way, if you think you know a better one.

Comment: Just return the first line in case the last line corresponds to a certain file for each block

Comment: I think it would be best to do a pre-processing stage where you parse each paragraph and save the results as, say, a dict. From there retrieving the data will be trivial as `material_code = materials[texture]`

Comment: @AlexandreB. yes, edited.

Comment: @BlueRineS how can I divide into block?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I would like to avoid to alter the original file or create new ones

Comment: @Blueko, say you have the entire file as a string `filestring`. you can split it into blocks: `filestring.split("\n\n")`

Comment: Didn't mean to change nor create. While parsing the file create a database for the program

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```py
mapping = {}
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('newmtl'):
            material = line[len('newmtl '):-1]
        elif line.startswith('map_Kd'):
            file = line.split('/')[-1][:-1]
            mapping[file] = material
```

Then mapping is a `dict` with the relations you want:

```py
{'texture0.jpg': 'material_20_1_8', 'texture0.png': 'material_0_2_8'}
```

Comment: ok, it works but the file actually has returns '\n' as well, which I think the question didn't include, so printing `mapping` would give me `{'texture0.png\n': 'material_0_2_8\n', 'texture0.jpg\n': 'material_20_1_8\n'}`, still a good answer

Answer (score 2):

Iteratively:

```
import re

textures = ('texture0.jpg', 'texture0.png')
with open('input.txt') as f:
    pat = re.compile(r'\bmaterial_\S+')
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        m = pat.search(line)
        if m:
            material = m.group()
        elif line.endswith(textures):
            print(line.split('/')[-1], material)
```

The output:

```
texture0.png material_0_2_8
texture0.jpg material_20_1_8
```

Answer (score 0):

Who likes regular expressions may like this approach for its readability and efficiency.

[`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a sequence of matched groups (the parts of the regexp enclosed in brackets) for all matches of the regular expression in the input data.  The regular expression thus finds all occurences of the "newmtl" line with the nearest following "map_Kd" line and extracts the value parts from those lines using regex groups.  The values are then just reversed to create the needed dictionary through [dictionary comprehension](https://timothybramlett.com/List_and_Dict_Comprehensions_in_Python.html).

I like this solution because it is compact and efficient.  Notice, I added just one (well, multiline) expression into the original example (and one import, to be exact).  If you can read regular expressions, it is also well readable.

```
import re

f = open('path/to/file', "r")
if f.mode == 'r':
    contents = f.read()  # contains the string shown above

materials = {
    filename: material for material, filename in 
    re.findall(r'^newmtl (material_\S+)$.*?^map_Kd \.\./images/(.+?)$', 
               contents, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
}

for texture in textures: # textures is the list of the texture names
    material_code = materials[texture]
```

The regular expression in this example works with given data.  If you need to be more strict or more permissive regarding whitespace or other kind of variability in the source data, it may need to be further tuned.